# Modifying a Google doc template and then sending it as a docx in an email whenever a google form is filled in

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to modify a template document with pertinent information from a google form submission and then send an email with the filled in document as a word doc to the person who filled the form in. I can manage to update the template and I can even get as far as attaching it as a pdf, but it needs to be editable by the receiver so that isn't really an option. Here is my code:

```
//Set template variables
var docTemplate = "1_l4T-MVXYXWPvirgE9aE25hKOejTqf9AcfHCKRC67Fk";
var docName = "Editorial Briefing Form";

//Get pertinent info from form
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var timeStamp = e.values[1];
  var RequestorName = e.values[2];
  var Account = e.values[3];
  var JobNumber = e.values[4];
  var Files = e.values[6];
  var StartDate = e.values[7];
  var BudgetHours = e.values[8];
  var ActualDeadline = e.values[10];
  var Email = e.values[11];

  // Get template and save a copy with a new name
  var copyId = DriveApp.getFileById(docTemplate)
  .makeCopy(docName+' for '+RequestorName)
  .getId();

  var copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId);

  var copyBody = copyDoc.getActiveSection();

//replace tags with form info
  copyBody.replaceText('keyAccount', Account);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyJobNumber', JobNumber);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyStartDate', StartDate);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyRequestorName', RequestorName);
  copyBody.replaceText('KeyFiles', Files);
  copyBody.replaceText('KeyBudgetHours',BudgetHours);
  copyBody.replaceText('KeyActualDeadline', ActualDeadline);

  copyDoc.saveAndClose()


MailApp.sendEmail(Email, 'test', 'see attachment', {attachments:[copyDoc]});
}
```

The only thing I've seen online involves Google OAuth, but I have no idea about that.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Thanks

Tom

Comment: You can consider using the [Document Studio](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/document-studio/nhgeilcelhkmajkfgmgldbinmgjjajlb) addon. It automatically converts a Google Form submission to any file format including .docx files using a template. (Disclaimer: I am the author)

Answer (score 1):

I just figured out something similar.  I couldn't get it to work from onFormSubmit(e), but I set it to run as a trigger from spreadsheet on form submit, and then told it to grab the last row of data, because forms submit puts that data in the last row (unless you have another script sorting things).  So, my code looked like this:

```
function FormSubmitEmail(){

    var templateid = "your template id here";
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var row = sheet.getLastRow();
    var data = sheet.getRange(5,1,sheet.getLastRow()-1,sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    var today = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "CST", "MM/dd/yy");
    var firstname = sheet.getRange("B"+row).getValues();
    var lastname = sheet.getRange("C"+row).getValues();
    var docname = (lastname+", "+firstname+" "+today);

    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("I have mine saving a copy also to a folder, your folder ID here"); 
    var docid = DriveApp.getFileById(templateid).makeCopy(docname, folder).getId(); 
    Logger.log(docid);

    var doc = DocumentApp.openById(docid);
    var body = doc.getActiveSection();
        body.replaceText("%DateCreated%",(sheet.getRange("A"+row).getValues()));
        body.replaceText("%FirstName%",(sheet.getRange("B"+row).getValues()));
        body.replaceText("%LastName%",(sheet.getRange("C"+row).getValues()));
        body.replaceText("%EmailAddress%",(sheet.getRange("M"+row).getValues()));  //etc.

    doc.saveAndClose();

    var message = "See attached, or find in folder: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/[your folder id here]"; // Customize message
    var emailTo = "email2@gmail.com, email1@gmail.com" // replace with your email
    var subject = "A form has been submitted!."; // customize subject 
    var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(docid).getAs('application/pdf').getBytes();
    var attach = {fileName:'Autogenerated template.pdf',content:pdf, mimeType:'application/pdf'}; // customize file name: "Autogenerated template"
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailTo, subject, message, {attachments:[attach]});
}
```